# How to apply centre manifold theorem in the following system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am learning the centre manifold. One theorem is as follows

> Suppose the zero solution of our centre manifold system is stable, then the zero solution of our originating system is also stable.

I am looking the following example:
$$
x'=x^2y-x^5, y'=-y+x^2
$$

Clearly, $(0,0)$ is a fixed point. I am confused how to check its stability.

We have the matrix of linearization $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$
with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=-1$.

But why it said that "we find $y=h(x)=x^2+o(x^4)$, it follows that the dynamics on the centre manifold is dictated by $x'=x^4-x^5+o(x^8)$."

So I am confused if $(0,0)$ stable or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $y = y(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$ we have

$$
\dot y = y_x\dot x = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k a_k x^{k-1}\right)\left(x^2\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k\right)-x^5\right)=-\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k+x^2
$$

having

$$
a_1+(a_2-1)x+(a_1^2+a_3)x^2+\cdots + = 0\ \ \forall x
$$

thus obtaining

$$
y = x^2 + O(x^5)
$$

then the origin dynamics is given by

$$
\dot x = x^2(x^2+O(x^5))-x^5
$$

[image]

NOTE

$\dot x = x^4-x^5$ is clearly unstable.